# jquery for validation

Tags: jquery

I used this jquery code for validation, but when I used this code my registration button it is not working. When I comment this code its working fine the data will save into the db

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug : true,
        success : "valid"
    });
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules : {
            email : {
                required : true,
                email : true
            },
            mobileNumber : {
                required : true,
                number : true
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can u please check in developer tools console tab are you getting error over there?

Comment: Be more specific about what is not working. Also, do share the HTML.

Comment: No i am not getting any error

Comment: Sir can you tell me how to display database dynamic data menu and submenus using jquery ..